# Convert long to wide format with "reshape" in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have a long format data set that I want to change into wide. I have tried to use the "reshape" function from the "reshape" library to do it.

My dataset "df_long" has the following three columns:

1. a numeric "ID" variable
2. a character variable "positive" ("true positive", "false positive")
3. a numeric "coder" variable (1,2)

I have made sure that for each value of "coder" I have just one value of "ID."

[my input data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWI7y.png)

I want to transform it into wide format so that I have one row for each ID with the columns positive_coder1 and positive_coder2. This is the reshape code I used.

```
df_wide <- reshape(df_long, v.names = c("positive"), timevar = "coder", 
                idvar = "ID", direction = "wide", sep = "_")
```

What I get is this:

[my output data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS5jO.png)

There are no NAs in my input data. What am I missing?

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example for testing

Comment: reshape is perfectly valid, but note that `dplyr::pivot_wider` is a more up to date method

Comment: Thanks, both. I will check out the dplyr function too. 

@akrun The problem is solved with duck's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you had is related with the type of your data structure. This is what you need before the reshaping. In this little example you will get one `NA` as data is only showing a portion but in your real dataset, there would not be issues:

```
#Transform
df_long <- as.data.frame(df_long)
#Code
df_wide <- reshape(df_long, v.names = c("positive"), timevar = "coder", 
                   idvar = "ID", direction = "wide", sep = "_")
```

Output:

```
df_wide
         ID    positive_2     positive_1
1 147256167 True positive False positive
3 147256191 True positive False positive
5 147256290 True positive  True positive
7 147256379 True positive           <NA>
```

Let's check your error in this way. We will assume that `df_long` has next classes:

```
class(df_long)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

If we apply the reshaping we will get:

```
df_wide
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID        `positive_c(2, 1)`
  <chr>     <chr>             
1 147256167 NA                
2 147256191 NA                
3 147256290 NA                
4 147256379 NA
```

Your same output, so the issue is related with `tibble` class. And using `df_long <- as.data.frame(df_long)` will alleviate the issue.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df_long <- structure(list(ID = c("147256167", "147256167", "147256191", 
"147256191", "147256290", "147256290", "147256379"), positive = c("True positive", 
"False positive", "True positive", "False positive", "True positive", 
"True positive", "True positive"), coder = c(2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Having tibbles, you could use some functions from `tidyr` like these:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
df_wide <- df_long %>% pivot_wider(names_from = coder,values_from=positive,
                        names_prefix = 'positive_')
```

With output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  ID        positive_2    positive_1    
  <chr>     <chr>         <chr>         
1 147256167 True positive False positive
2 147256191 True positive False positive
3 147256290 True positive True positive 
4 147256379 True positive NA
```

Last one can be an option for you as you are mainly using `reshape()`.

Comment: That has indeed solved the issue! So simple ... Thank you. @duck